# Adding ARToolKit SDK to Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

ARToolKit is a library to create augmented reality aplications. I wanna know how to create Android AR apps and I have chosen this tool for this. I'm using Android Studio SDK in Windows7 and I have downloaded and unzip the ARToolKit5-bin-5.3.2-Android and then I have imported and proved the ARSimple example that is included in that package.
Well then, I wanna research into RA by myself creating my own app. For that, I need to add the ARToolKit package to my project and like this I can use the AR classes and methods, but I don't known how do it.
Please, is anyone there that can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider using ARToolKit v6? Might be easier to integrate: artoolkit.org

Comment: Yes, I have considered use ARToolKit v6, but I have the same problem: I don't know how to add the library to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=== UPDATE 1: 15/Feb/2018 ===

For all of you that might read that in the future. The download of ARToolKit6 was taken down by DAQRI and I'm unsure if the program will be continued.

=== ORIGINAL post ===

I can tell you the steps for ARToolKit6. I'm aware that you have asked for the steps for ARToolKit5 but I believe they are not that different.

In short, these are the things that you need to do:

1. Open your project
2. Right click your app > Open Module Settings
3. In the top left select the `+`
4. Select `Import .JAR/.AAR Package` > Next
5. As `File name` on the right select `...` and then navigate to the .aar file in the unziped ARToolKit6 Android SDK

   - Should be << ARToolKit6 Android SDK >>/SDK/lib/AR6J/AR6J-release.aar
6. Close the `Open Module Settings` dialouge with `OK`
7. Open it again Right click your app > Open Module Settings

   - There seems to be an issue with Android Studio reloading imported modules. That is why you need to close and open it again.
8. Select your app on the left and navigate to `Dependencies` tab
9. On the bottom left select the `+` > Module Dependencies and select AR6J-release

[image: Module Dependencies]

You can find a longer description and a step by step video on this page:
http://augmentmy.world/integrate-artoolkit6-android-sdk

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have replicated the procedure with artoolkit5. That package has a different folder distribution, then, I have searched inside the artoolkit5 folder the .arr file and I have found 'aRBaseLib-release.aar'. Next to this, I have added the .aar the same way that you explained. I can import the package to the project, it seems that works!

Comment: I could not find ARToolkit6 to download!

Comment: @JayPatel DAQRI took the download down. You can use artoolkit5 https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5 for now

Comment: But I don't know how to configure artoolkit5! Can you help?

Comment: You can use that as a starting point and ping me if you got specific questions. https://archive.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_about